Aes encrypted byte array is empty
I am implementing an encryption/decryption methods as in this example. The problem is that the byte array in EncryptString method is empty; thus, the resulting string is empty too. How to solve the problem?
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

Crypto crypto = new();

string test = "test";

string encrypted = crypto.EncryptString(test);
string decrypted = crypto.DecryptString(encrypted);

Console.WriteLine($"{test}\n{encrypted}\n{decrypted}");
Console.ReadKey();

class Crypto
{
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("01234567890123456789012345678901");
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];

    public string EncryptString(string plainText)
    {
        using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
        using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        using StreamWriter streamWriter = new(cryptoStream);

        streamWriter.Write(plainText);

        // Array is empty here
        byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array);
    }

    public string DecryptString(string cipherText)
    {
        using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using MemoryStream memoryStream = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cipherText));
        using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        using StreamReader streamReader = new(cryptoStream);

        string decrypted = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        return decrypted;
    }
}


There's a reason why the sample in the page you're working from is using using statements rather than using declarations. Perhaps start from exactly the code in the sample and then modify it more slowly/carefully.

Yes, it seems like the StreamWriter has to be disposed before calling the MemoryStream

You can Flush() it instead

@JoelCoehoorn just Flush() on StreamWriter is not enough in this case. Yes it will write data to underlying CryptoStream and even will call Flush on that CryptoStream, but you need to call FlushFinalBlock and that will not be done. Closing StreamWriter though will close underlying CryptoStream in this case, and will flush final block.

Note that in code you are trying to copy they have:
using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
{
      //Write all data to the stream.
      swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
}
encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

StreamWriter is closed (disposed) before calling msEncrypt.ToArray(). In your code it's not the same - StreamWriter is not closed till the end of the scope (because of using statements), so when using memoryStream.ToArray() - there is nothing written to that stream yet. Simple fix:
using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
using StreamWriter streamWriter = new(cryptoStream);

streamWriter.Write(plainText);
streamWriter.Close();
byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();

Or better - just don't use scope-sized using statements where it's not necessary.
Also, do NOT use UTF8 encoding for the result of encryption. Result of encryption is binary data, it's not a text. If you must store it as string - use something like base64 encoding, not text encoding like UTF8.

Good catch on the UTF8 part. If you hadn't noticed, I was gonna have to make an answer (community wiki, since it wouldn't actually address the question) to point that out. He might also want to reconsider the encoding earlier, since .Net strings are not UTF8 by default. Also, I'd make the Crypto type require the Key as part of the constructor, rather than hard-coding it.

@JoelCoehoorn iv is also hard coded in this case (all zeroes) which kinda defeats its purpose.
